# Using the ScrollView in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, uiscrollview

I had a long text in the screen so definitely scrolling is the only option. However, when I enter the ScrollView, an error is shown as

"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_width attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
"" does not set the required layout_height attribute:
 (1) Set to "wrap_content"
 (2) Set to "match_parent"
You must supply a layout_height attribute.

Here is my .xml file

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.projextxy.CityInfo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=" all the text goes in here "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent" >

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Your included code seems incomplete. Please post the complete content of your layout XML file and indicate at which lines the errors occur.

Comment: @cygery Thats the complete XML file. The error occurs in the TextView layout_alignParentLedt and layout_alignParentTop . It shows " invaled layout param in a scroll view "

Comment: You have a closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag but no corresponding opening tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you used the layout editor to drag and drop the scrollview in so it ends up looking weird because what you posted is a completely mis-formatted XML file.

To simplify it, just remove all the the attributes and it should become apparent what the problem is:

```
<ScrollView    <-- start a ScrollView
    >

    <TextView <-- start and end a TextView
         />
    </ScrollView> <-- end a ScrollView

</RelativeLayout> <-- end a RelativeLayout
<ScrollView <-- start a ScrollView
>

</ScrollView>  <-- end a ScrollView
```

As you see it is completely out of whack. just change it to this:

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.projextxy.CityInfo" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text=" all the text goes in here "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</ScrollView>
```

The rest is not needed